# how to compute the probability that a random graph has two components?

Tags: probability, random-graphs

This question is an example in the book Introduction to Probability Models 11th edition (Sheldon M.Ross). 3.6.2 A random graph:

A graph has $V$ nodes and a set $A$ of pairs of nodes in $V$ called arcs.
$V = \{1,2,...n\}$ and $A = \{(i,X(i), i=1,...,n\}$. The probability that node $i$ is connected to node $j$ is:

$P\{X(i)=j\}=\frac{1}{n}, j=1,2,...,n$

If from each node $i$, we select at random ONE of the $n$ nodes (including $i$ itself), what is the probability the graph is connected (there is a path between each pair of the $\binom{n}{2}$ nodes)?

I understand the proof of this part that this probability is: $P\{graph\ is\ connected\} \approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n(-1)}}.$

In the second part, we want to calculate the probability that there are 2 components in the random graph. Say nodes $1,2,3,...,k$ is connected, and nodes $k+1,...,n$ is connected. Let $C$ denotes the number of connected components. $P_n(i)=P\{C=i\}$.

To calculate $P_n(2)$, we need to use:

$P\{X(i)\in\{1,2,...,k\}, for\ all\ i=1,...,k\}=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k$

$P\{X(i)\in\{k+1,...,n\}, for\ all\ i=k+1,...,n\}=\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$

$P\{nodes\ 1,2,3,...,k\ form\ a\ connected\ subgraph\}=P_k(1)$

$P\{nodes\ k+1,...,n\ form\ a\ connected\ subgraph\}=P_{n-k}(1)$

So the point I DON'T understand is: because there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways of choosing a set of $k-1$ nodes from the nodes $2$ through $n$, we have:

$P_n(2)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}P_k(1)P_{n-k}(1)$

Why we choose $k-1$ from $n-1$ rather than choose $k$ from $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are choosing the other $k-1$ nodes to share a component with node $1$.

$k$ is not the number of nodes in "one of the components". After all, there are two components, so which one would $k$ represent? Instead, $k$ is the number of nodes in the component containing node $1$. And since you already know that node $1$ is in that component, you only need to choose $k-1$ nodes to be its compatriots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why node 1 is special in this case? We just need to select k nodes for component 1 and the remaining component 2, is there any problem with this?

Comment: What differentiates component 1 from component 2? For any "component 1" you pick for some given $k$, you will also pick its complement for $n-k$, thus counting this pair of components twice. You can prevent this by only letting $k$ run up to $\left\lceil \frac n2\right\rceil$, but even then when $n$ is even, you will also need to divide the count for $k=\frac n2$ by $2$ to account for the duplication of component pairs. You can do this, but it is a more complicated analysis than just picking a node at the start, and counting instead the components of which it is a part.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!